# Conditional move depends on an unitialised variable C and double for loop

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, valgrind

I tried making a simple prime numbers sorting algorithm called Sieve of Eratosthenes and I tried making that via a double `for` loop. But valgrind returns a warning:

> Conditional move depends on an uninitialized variable, due to stack
>   allocation.

Is the way I wrote the second `for` loop not possible in C?

The primes are supposed to be less than 1000000

Here is the code:

```
int range = 1000000;

int main()
{
    int all_nums[range];

    for (int i=2;i<range;i++)
    {
        all_nums[i-2]=i;
    }

    int sieve[range];

    for (int i=0;i<range;i++)
    {
        sieve[i]=0;
    }

    // this is where the problem starts

    int index_sieve = 0;
    float max_sqrt = sqrt(range);

    for (int i = 0; i < range; i++)
    {
        if (all_nums[i] != 0 && all_nums[i]<max_sqrt)
        {
            sito[index_sieve] = all_nums[i];
            index_sieve += 1;
            for (int x = i+1; x<range; x++)
            {
                if (all_nums[x] != 0 && all_nums[x] % all_nums[i] == 0)
                {
                    all_nums[x] = 0;
                }
            }   
        }
        else if (all_nums[i] != 0 && all_nums[i] > max_sqrt)
        {
            sieve[index_sieve] = all_nums[i];
            index_sieve += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what it does is, it checks numbers from 2 up until 1000000. If the number isn't 0, I save it and try to divide every higher number. If there is no remainder I turn that number into 0, the second `for` loop ends and I go back to first `for` loop to take another number.

There is a little condition at the `else if` line that says: **if the number I'm looking at is smaller than the biggest number in the range, then this and every higher number is prime**

I suspect that I cannot write the second `for` loop like that, but I'm new to C and I might be wrong, but other than that, I can't find anything uninitialized.

Comment: `all_nums[i-2]` - `all_unums[range-1]` and `all_nums[range-2]` are uniniitliazed.

Comment: Oh wow, I have to find out why. I couldn't find them. Thanks a lot, really appreciate it

Comment: Fixing indentation would be a good idea, too.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.